# Redirect User Back to same URL after posting data in golang

Tags: go, web, redirect

I want to redirect user to the page that he has came from after serving a form and taking the input from that form upon successful submission he has to redirect to the same page.

I want this to be done in Golang. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
http.Redirect(w, r, r.Header.Get("Referer"), 302)
```

r.Header.Get("Referer") always contains the referring url for current page ( which is previous url)

**Update**

As you have said in comment that your are using same url for post and get. In that case it will be update the get url as your refer url.

In this situation you can pass the url as parameter  so on success you can
 redirect user to that url.

**For example,
If, user gets redirect to the upload page from home page then make url like this,**

http://example.com/upload?redir=http://example.com/home

So now you have knowladge from which page the user was landed this page 
just redirect it to the redir url you got from url.

```
 redirect_url = r.FormValue("redir)
 http.Redirect(w, r, redirect_url , 302)
```

Comment: But i handle the Get and And POST on same URL so that it stores the previous URL as GET. and What i want is that i want to redirect to page that has got me into the GET URL page